# How do you place an image and make it move using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, animation

CSS:

```
#sharks {
    content:url(sharks.jpg);
    position:absolute;
}
```

JS:

```
var winHeight = window.innerHeight;// get the window height & width
var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
var clock;
var index = 0;

function do_move(image) {
    fish = document.getElementById(image);
    horz = fish.style.left;
    horz = parseInt(horz.substring(0,horz.length-2));
    fish.style.left = (horz+1)+'px';
}

function add_shark() {

    var height = Math.floor((Math.random()*winHeight)+100);
    var image = document.createElement("IMG");
    image.setAttribute("id", "sharks" + index);
    image.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;top:"+height+"px;left:0px;");
    document.body.appendChild(image);
    do_move(image.id);
    index++;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Add a Shark" onclick="add_shark();">
```

Looking at this code, I am hoping the use the button in the HTML to place an image of a shark on one side of the screen that will simply move to the other side.

Currently, this code places a shark on the screen on the left side, at a random Y point, but it doesn't move.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By 'move to the other side of the screen' do you mean you want it animated? As in it slowly slides over to the other side?

Comment: You should really look into jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: @fos.alex Or he could learn how to do animation himself.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher true, but why would you waste time doing something that has already been successfully done instead of building upon it.

Comment: @fos.alex - To learn how.  Some people want to understand how their tools work.

Comment: What Jeremy said, I am trying to learn how it operates, but I would like to learn jQuery later. Thanks for the help, it has helped me to make a minor discovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to use window.setTimeout() to have your move function call itself over and over to make the animation happen.

This could *should* be close to what you want, but I haven't actually run it yet:

```
function do_move(image) {
    fish = document.getElementById(image);
    horz = fish.style.left;
    horz = parseInt(horz.substring(0,horz.length-2));

    // How far we are moving the image each "step"
    horz += 10;
    fish.style.left = (horz)+'px';

    // The total distance we are moving the image
    if (horz < 500) {
      // Set things up to call again
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        do_move(image);
      }, 250);  // 1/4 of a second
    }
}
```